# Append text to freeradius files using php

Tags: php, chmod, freeradius, chown

I want to update freeradius files using php because my system will working in different machines 
for example (if user want to add ldap database to freeradius he just write ldap server, username, password after that system automatically will add this data to ldap file)
ldap file's path:/etc/freeradius/modules/ldap
but when I using

```
 $myfile = file_put_contents('/etc/freeradius/moldules/ldap', $txt);
```

there is nothing happen 
.
here is the permission of freeradius files

```
drws--S--- 7 freerad freerad ? 4096 Dec  4 16:32 /etc/freeradius/
```

I tried to change own of freeradius folder to www-data but without any result 
when the system try to add the text to file there is no any error appear but without result

Comment: Does the error log contain any information? Have you tried creating the folder you want to write to first?

Comment: the error.log does not contain any thing , the folder is already  exists